# Load HTML in WebView with local css and js

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-webview

I am displaying a webview with a remote html content get as a string from a remote server. 
I store the html locally for a no connection use of my application.

Moreover I also store a .js script and a .css style file locally. These files can be updated by the server.

I store all these files at the following paths :

```
context.getFilesDir()+"content.css"
context.getFilesDir()+"content.js"
```

In the html string, css and js are referenced like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content.css" type="text/css" media="screen">                                            
<script src="/content.js"></script>
```

I load the html using

```
this.webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), html, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

But the style and the js are not taken into account, so I think something is wrong with the path I use to reference them, or to load the webView. So what is the way to do this ? I found many answers that use the "assets" folder but I do not want to use it since I have to update the css and the js from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution :

- The css (or js) file is saved in local using this method :

  `public static void writeToFile(Context context, String content, String title) throws IOException
  {

      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(title,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE));
      osw.write(content);
      osw.close();
  }`
- Then I refer it in the html file using

  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="content.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

  <script src="content.js"></script>`
- And finally I have opened the webview using :

  `this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  this.webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); 
  this.webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  this.webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  this.webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
  this.webView.setWebViewClient(this.controller.getWebViewClient());
  String basePath = "file://"+getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
  this.webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(basePath, data, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");`